# Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken and Azure Portal

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

We would like to be able to terminate browser sessions connected to the Azure Portal, when we detect activity originating from an untrusted location / IP Address.  As the Azure Portal is a confidential client, with a non-configurable Refresh Token that is valid until-revoked, we are looking to the AAD PowerShell cmdlet, `Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken`.  Per the document, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0,

> “The cmdlet also invalidates tokens issued to session cookies in a
>   browser for the user.”

As a test, and after a user logged onto the Azure Portal,  I executed the cmdlet against the user’s object ID.  Then, the user received

> “Experiencing authentication issues”

errors when navigating around his session, but, still, was able to continue to access and modify resources.  Images are attached / linked.

[image: Image of Error]
[image: Image of Error]

I was advised to submit this question, here, at stackoverflow for help with investigating why users, still, have a live session to the Azure Portal, even after issuing the `Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken` cmdlet.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How long did this issue happened after using `Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken` cmdlet ? This cmdlet won't take effect at once.

Comment: Hi, Wayne.  I tried against two different accounts.  Account A took about 10 minutes; while, account B took about two minutes.  In both tests, I was hoping that the sessions would terminate, but they did not.  Would you happen to know what our experience should be, with regard to timing and browser session?

Comment: Doesn't the cmdlet just revoke refresh tokens? In that case it makes sense apps will still work for a while since access tokens have a default lifetime of one hour.

Comment: Hi, @juunas.  I see what you mean.  However, from the document, it mentions that, "The cmdlet also invalidates tokens issued to session cookies in a browser for the user."  Since the Azure Portal is a confidential client, I am under the impression that a user's session token could be revoked or invalidated, on demand.

Comment: Hmm, well it could be true. But based on your experiment, it should then be a bug in AAD or the portal, or the fact is that the tokens work after that command runs for a while still.